# Where does R look for objects when doing `eval`?

Tags: r

Let's evaluate an expression in an environment:

```
> myenv <- new.env()
> assign("x", 2, myenv)
> f <- function(x) x+1
> eval(expression(f(x)), myenv)
[1] 3
```

I don't understand why it works, because `f` is not in `myenv`. How does R find `f`?

Let's look at the help:

```
Usage

eval(expr, envir = parent.frame(),
           enclos = if(is.list(envir) || is.pairlist(envir))
                       parent.frame() else baseenv())

Arguments

envir   
the environment in which expr is to be evaluated. May also be NULL, a list, a data frame, a pairlist or an integer as specified to sys.call.
enclos  
Relevant when envir is a (pair)list or a data frame. Specifies the enclosure, i.e., where R looks for objects not found in envir. This can be NULL (interpreted as the base package environment, baseenv()) or an environment.
```

So it says that R also looks in `enclos`, which is `baseenv()` here. But `f` is not in `baseenv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `myenv <- new.env()`, by default it sets the parent environment of your new environment to the current environment. The signature is

```
new.env(hash = TRUE, parent = parent.frame(), size = 29L)
```

So if a symbol name isn't resolved in the environment you execute the expression in, R will check the chain of parent environments. You can disable that behavior by specifying an empty environment as the parent environment.

```
myenv <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
assign("x", 2, myenv)
f <- function(x) x+1
eval(expression(f(x)), myenv)
# Error in f(x) : could not find function "f"
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I find the documentation not clear. But maybe I'm the one who misunderstands...

Comment: Using `enclos` makes more sense when your `envir=` parameter isn't an environment that can have a parent environment -- such as when `envir=` is a list or a data.frame.